# Why this default OVER () behavior for the frame?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I've noticed from the following two window functions:

```
WITH sales AS (
    select 2020 as year, 100 as revenue UNION
    select 2021 as year, 200 as revenue UNION
    select 2022 as year, 300 as revenue UNION
    select 2023 as year, 100 as revenue
)
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(revenue) OVER (order by year) FROM sales LIMIT 1;

# revenue_list
[100]
```

And this:

```
WITH sales AS (
    select 2020 as year, 100 as revenue UNION
    select 2021 as year, 200 as revenue UNION
    select 2022 as year, 300 as revenue UNION
    select 2023 as year, 100 as revenue
)
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(revenue) OVER () revenue_list FROM sales LIMIT 1;
# revenue_list
[100, 200, 300, 100]
```

It seems like the default behavior of the frame is:

- If nothing is supplied -- `()` -- then default frame is `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`
- If anything supplied -- `(order by year)` or `(partition by year)`, etc -- then default frame is `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

Is that a correct understanding of the default frame behavior? If so, why was that choice made? (For example, why not just have it always unbounded unless specified by the user?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIMIT 1` clause in the first query is misleading you.  Consider the full query without any `LIMIT` clause:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(revenue) OVER (ORDER BY year) FROM sales;
```

The result set generated from this is:

[image: screen capture]

The reason that `[100]` gets returned...is totally arbitrary.  You don't have an `ORDER BY` clause with your `LIMIT` query, so the "first" record we see in the result set just happens to get returned (but it could, in theory, be *any* of the four records).

The `OVER ()` version would just render the entire table aggregated into a JSON array, but would display that value for each record.

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(revenue) OVER () FROM sales;  -- [100, 200, 300, 100] each record
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(revenue) FROM sales;          -- [100, 200, 300, 100] one record
```

Comment: in other words, the default frame is always `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` ?

Comment: Yes, correct.  So `OVER (ORDER BY year)` is identical to `OVER (ORDER BY year ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` ... but we typically always would just use the former for brevity.